# apk installed via adb is not visible in "my apps" section of google play store

Tags: android, apk, adb, google-play

I've a similar problem than this one (though this is not a duplicate as my question is a bit different) :
[Is it possible to install an application via adb but still get Google Market updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842890/is-it-possible-to-install-an-application-via-adb-but-still-get-google-market-upd)

Here is a list of steps that led to my problem :

1. I've pulled an apk (previously installed through google play store) from my phone with *adb pull* for backup purpose.
2. I uninstalled it.
3. A new version of this app appears on the market.
4. I then choose to re-install my apk that I've previously saved (at step 1) through adb

The problem is the following : it is not visible in the "my apps" section of the play store. Why ?

- I've already checked, the package names are the same.
- If I choose to search for this app on the google play store, it shows that it is already installed and that I can update (I indeed, can update and everything goes fine).
- I've tried with different apps, they ALL have the same behaviour.
- I've tried different method of installation (*adb install -r*, *adb shell pm install* [which is, among other things, basically what *adb install* does])
- I've already tried to clear data / stop the play store app
- I've already tried to restart my phone

My question is simple : **why this is happening** ?

Comment: because you did not install it via gplay

Comment: I already figured this out :) I guess my formulation was not right. A more correct question would have been : Is there a way to make an app installed via adb appears on the "my apps" section of the play store ? The strange thing for me is that when I search for it on the play store, I can see the app is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is poosible in any way, because in "my apps" do only appera apps you have downloaded from gplay. So in their database you have downloaded the app, if you called "Download" via the app or the Webpage of GPlay. If you open the GPlay app and search for the "installed" app it can be started, because the GPlay app checks internaly weather the app is reachable via the intent (e.g. Intent("com.rivio.angrybirdpro"). So you can open it directly but it is not listed in "my apps"
If you install apps from the amazon market they do not appear in gplay's "my apps" either.

Hope this is what you were asking for.